# ArgumentExcept Unity5 Erro input axis horizontal is not setup

Tags: c#, unity-5

Estou  tentando  seguir o tutorial do jogo **"Nightmare**" do canal **jogando com nils**, meu script não apresenta nenhum erro, porém meu personagem não se move e a `Unity 5`  mostra esse erro relacionado ao axis horizontal. Conferi o vídeo do Nils e ele não altera nada no `Axis`, só mostra. 
Assim não consigo mover meu personagem e ele entra na animação Idle. agradeço desde já.
segue a baixo o erro apresentado pela `Unity 5`

> ArgumentException: Input Axis horizontal is not setup.  To change the
>   input settings use: Edit -> Project Settings -> Input
>   PlayerMovement.FixedUpdate () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Player/PlayerMovement.cs:37)

segue o código `PlayerMovement.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //velocidade do jogador
    public float speed = 6f;

    //vetor responspável pelo movimento
    Vector3 movement;          

    //responsável pela animação              
    Animator anim; 

    //responsável pela física do objeto
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;

    //máscara de chão
    int floorMask;

    //inf para o Raycast
    float camRayLenght = 100f;


        void awake()
    {
        //atribuir a máscara da camada
        floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Floor");

        //atribuir as referências
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("vertical");

        Move(h, v);
        Turning();
        Animating(h, v);
    }



    void Move(float h, float v)
    {
        //determina o movimento
        movement.Set(h, 0f, v);

        //normaliza o movimento
        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        //efetua o movimento no personagem
        playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
    }

    //girar o jogador  
    void Turning()
    {
        Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        RaycastHit floorHit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(camRay,out floorHit, camRayLenght, floorMask))
        {
            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
            playerToMouse.y = 0f;
            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);

        }

    }
    void Animating(float h, float v)
    {
        bool walking = (h != 0f || v != 0f);
        anim.SetBool("IsWalking", walking);

    }


}
```

segue foto do input Horizontal que está sendo relatado no erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Continuei seguindo o tutorial e tudo está dando certo exceto pelo fato de que não consigo me movimentar e nem o mouse é seguido, porém agora o console mostra um erro na linha 56 que é esta aqui:

```
    //efetua o movimento no personagem
    playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
```

Comment: Poste o código do PlayerMovement.cs

Comment: acabei de postar o código junto a pergunta

Comment: Tentou colocar Horizontal e Vertical com a primeira letra maiúscula?

Comment: não, mas tentarei mesmo achando que como esta entre aspas não alteraria.

Comment: Pode ter certeza que altera kk

Comment: isso não mudou nada como pensei.

Comment: Vá na aba Edit -> Project Settings -> Input, você verá os controles do jogo, note que há Horizontal e Vertical (por isso lestras maiúsculas são importantes) verifique se estão corretas, com Axis X e Y

Comment: Aqui no meu Unity 5 funcionou perfeitamente, com certeza são seus inputs que estão configurados errados.

Comment: postarei fotos o meu input mas   eu ja resetei uma vez ate pro caso de estarem errados e nada    e no video o nil nao altera nada nos axis somente mostra que ali voce pode configurar  os controles do jogo

Comment: pronto ai está.